# Additions & Twists

Tags: word, anagram, letters

**Start with a word.**
For each line below, **add one letter** to the last word, then **anagram**, to get a word that means:

- pitch
- fleet
- slowly
- anent
- public
- adverse

**What word did I start as** and what words did I become?

<sub>*Part of a <kbd>[metapuzzles](/questions/tagged/metapuzzles)</kbd> entry: **[I, for one, welcome our new ...](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51078/i-for-one-welcome-our-new)***</sub>

Comment: "anent", the archaic Scottish preposition, or is that a typo?

Comment: @randal'thor It is not a typo.

Comment: What do you mean by "last word" ?

Comment: @DavidHuang The word from the prior line (or the initial word, for the first line).  I probably should have said "previous" - sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word you started with was

> AT

The sequence is as follows:

> TAR
>  
>  DART
>  
>  [TARDO](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tardo)
>  
>  TOWARD
>  
>  OUTWARD
>
>  UNTOWARD

This matches up with the title because

> AT also stands for "Additions & Twists" (thanks @BeastlyGerbil)

Comment: There's two good ways to know which of the two words you offered as first word is correct.

Comment: How does your second word mean "fleet"?

Comment: The first word was AT from **A**dditions and **T**wists

Comment: @randal'thor In the same sense as an expression fleeting across someone's face. It's not the most common usage, but I think it's valid.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil That's one of the two ways.  There's another also, not that it's important.